# How to disable the play button of an Apple Remote in OSX?

Tags: macos, keynote, remote-control, customization, bettertouchtool

I sometimes accidentally hit the play/pause button of my Apple Remote while Keynote was in show mode, closing the active presentation. Therefore, I would like to disable the play/pause button; either globally or specifically for Keynote.

I thought that [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/) would help me out, but it doesn't. Setting up a new trigger for Keynote on the play button does not work (tried to set it on *Global* and on *Keynote*).

**Any tips on how I can disable the play/pause button?** Thanks!

Comment: maybe [keyremap4macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) can help you. Could you check in the eventviewer what key is reported when you press the remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have the "Enable Apple remote plugin" box checked under settings. Also, make sure under Action settings> settings for predefined actions you have the right remote type selected. Then, simply create a new trigger with the remote's play button and no action. It should disable the remote. (You may have to restart both keynote and better touch tool for the effect to take place)

Comment: I tried adding various actions, but that did not change anything: the default action was always triggered (i.e., in Keynote, stop the presentation; outside of Keynote, start playback in iTunes).

Comment: Do you have the "Enable Apple remote plugin" box checked under settings? Also, make sure under Action settings> settings for predefined actions you have the right remote type selected

Comment: The "Enable Apple remote plugin" was unchecked. I checked it now, and this allowed me to disable the play/pause button _globally_, but I still cannot change/disable it for Keynote.

Comment: Actually, restarting both BetterTouchTool and Keynote made it work. If you change your answer to this, then I can accept it! (The current answer is incorrect BTW, just having a blank action does disable it.)

Comment: It's all fixed up!